# Better way to organize the following snippet by avoiding too many json.getString

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Consider the following snippet

```
public static JSONObject getStudentDetails() throws Exception {
//returns the details as json
}

public static JSONObject getDepartmentDetails(String department_id) throws Exception {
//returns the details as json
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

JSONObject json1 = getStudentDetails();
String name = json1.getString(“name”);
String role_number = json1.getString(“role_number”);
String department_id = json1.getStrring(“department_id”);
//and goes on - to get all student details


JSONObject json2 = getDepartmentDetails(department_id);
String department_hod = json2.getString(“department_hod”);
String department_name = json2.getString(“department_name”);
String department_block = json2.getString(“department_block”);
//and goes on - till i get all the department details

//Followed by main action to be performed
}
```

In the above code for most of the case i am likely to call an util method which returns a json object which i am using in my doGet/doPost method. So most part of my code in my doPost/doGet is like to fetch values from json object with `getString`. Is there any better way to organise the above snippet?

Comment: have you tried json parser libraries like Gson or FastJSON?

Comment: No I haven't.. Thought of serialization and deserialization to be the costlier operations for multiple small jsons....

Comment: Then you should start to use one of them, because it will make your life easier and make your code better and cleaner. I suggest you start with FastJSON, because it is the best json parser(serializer/deserializer) out there in term of performance.

Comment: It's costlier to your time and keyboard longevity to type out the other code

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your start using JSON parser library. There are some JSON parser libraries that famous out there, for example: FastJSON, Jackson, Gson, etc.

If you don't want to use any external libraries, for cleaner code, you better to create a model to put your data there, and be sure as clear as possible when naming your variables. Because **there is no way to avoid** `json.getString` **without the help of external libraries**.

```
class Student{
    private String name;
    private String roleNumber;
    private String departmentId;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Student setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getRoleNumber() {
        return roleNumber;
    }

    public Student setRoleNumber(String roleNumber) {
        this.roleNumber = roleNumber;
        return this;
    }

    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public Student setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
        return this;
    }
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
    JSONObject studentJsonObject = getStudentDetails();
    Student student = new Student()
            .setName(studentJsonObject.getString("name"))
            .setRoleNumber(studentJsonObject.getString("role_number"))
            .setDepartmentId(studentJsonObject.getString("department_id"));

    //then you can easily get each property of student
    //like student.getName(); or student.getDepartmentId();

    //the rest of your code
}
```